# QR Code Link to Random Website from Selection

Tags: redirect, qr-code

I want to make a QR Code that when scanned, takes the user to a random website from a pre-defined list.

My first attempt was to use a Google Scripts editor to create a Web App then link that to the QR from a generic QR Code generator, but the App can't be made available for public use and the script I run doesn't work. My next attempt was to use a basic website maker like Wix (So it automatically publishes a website that can be linked to the QR Code) and use HTML to make a button that does that, however the Wix webpage can never establish a connection to the sites I have.

This is a brief hobby project I have going on, so I am making attempts to not have to purchase a domain/I want to try and make this free.

Answer (score 0):

You might find https://a.zat.is useful then. It should make it very easy to embed a small QR code for any URL. Let me know if you have any questions about its use ;)